# Memory management/leak in Excel sub with several do until loops

Tags: excel, vba, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have inherited an Excel workbook with the following VBA-code. The workbook contains SAP Analysis for Excel connections.
The sheet it is changing "Reconciliation" contains approximately 15000 rows.
And in column "A" we have a lot of numbers stored as text (it shows green markings in the corner of the cell).

The code traverses data and loops back and forth in data rows repeatedly.

My problem is, that the memory usage of the Excel application increases rapidly when running this sub.
And at some point it will crash Excel and run out of memory.

I have googled VBA Memory leaks and tried changing the following:

- Changing `Range("A" & i)` to `Cells(i, "A")`
- Added `.Value` to all cell value-references
- Added a workbook object to all `Range` and `Cells` references (`MyWorkbook.Range("A" & i).Value`)
- Moved variable definitions to the innermost level possible instead of in the start of the sub (j, r, c)

None of this has made any difference to the memory consumption.

If I Move the "Reconciliation"-sheet to a fresh workbook and copy the sub there, the sub runs and finishes almost instantly without any noticeably increase in memory-usage.

So, that would suggest, that the code is actually ok.

But I would appreciate any suggestions regarding memory heavy operations in the code?

```
Sub Reconciliation02()

Dim i As Long
Dim Resultatet As String
Dim MyWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'Application.Calculation = xlManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reconciliation").Select
Set MyWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reconciliation")
'ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select

i = 2
'LastRow = MyWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Do While i <= LastRow
Do Until MyWorksheet.Cells(i, "A").Value = ""
'Do Until MyWorksheet.Range("A" & i).Value = ""

    If Mid(MyWorksheet.Range("B" & i), 3, 1) = "/" Then
        MyWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value = Right(MyWorksheet.Range("B" & i), Len(MyWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value) - 3)
    End If

    If (MyWorksheet.Range("E" & i).Value <> "" And Right(MyWorksheet.Range("E" & i).Value, 1) <> "#") Then
        With MyWorksheet.Range("E" & i).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 5296274
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If

    If (MyWorksheet.Range("H" & i).Value <> "" And Right(MyWorksheet.Range("H" & i).Value, 1) <> "#") Then
        With MyWorksheet.Range("H" & i).Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If

    MyWorksheet.Cells(i, "W").Value = 1

    If MyWorksheet.Range("A" & i).Value = "#" Then
        MyWorksheet.Range("W" & i).Value = 1
    End If


    If (MyWorksheet.Range("B" & i).Value = "Result" And MyWorksheet.Range("A" & i).Value <> "#" And MyWorksheet.Range("S" & i).Value = 0) Then
        Dim j As Long
        Dim r As Long
        Dim c As Long

    '    'j = 0
    '    'r = 0
    '    'c = 0

        'Sætter "OK" hvis Result lig med 0
        MyWorksheet.Range("V" & i).Value = "OK"
        j = i - 1
        Do Until MyWorksheet.Range("A" & j).Value <> MyWorksheet.Range("A" & i).Value
            MyWorksheet.Range("V" & j).Value = "OK"
            j = j - 1
        Loop

        'tæller antal record per Reference
        c = j + 1
        Do Until c = i + 1
            MyWorksheet.Range("W" & c).Value = i - j
            c = c + 1
        Loop

        'Fjerner "OK" hvhis valuta ikke er ens på alle Reference linjer
        r = j
        Resultatet = "OK"
        Do Until r = i
            If (MyWorksheet.Range("Q" & r + 1).Value <> MyWorksheet.Range("Q" & r + 2).Value And r < i - 2) Then
                Resultatet = ""
                Do Until j = i
                    MyWorksheet.Range("V" & j + 1).Value = Resultatet
                    j = j + 1
                Loop
                r = i 'Vi need to exit the loop
            Else
                r = r + 1 'We need to carry on looping
            End If
        Loop

    End If 'Slut på total sum lig 0

    If (Range("B" & i) = "Result" And Range("A" & i) <> "#" And Range("S" & i) <> 0) Then
        j = i - 1
        Do Until Range("A" & j) <> Range("A" & i)
            j = j - 1
        Loop
        c = j + 1
        Do Until c = i + 1
            Range("W" & c).Value = i - j
            c = c + 1
        Loop

    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

MsgBox ("Færdig med punkt 2")

Set MyWorksheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Any chance you have some code in events handlers, like for example `Worksheet_Change` in sheet Reconciliation or `Workbook_SheetChange` in ThisWorkbook? If so you might want to disable the events for the duration of the function.

Comment: Are there also formulas involved that need to calculate during your code runs? If yes that could cause the high memory usage. If there are no formulas, then reading the data into an array, performing all actions on that array and then writing it back to the worksheet can reduce the heavy load of read/write actions on cells to only one read/write action. You will find many tutorials how to read/write worksheet data into arrays.

Comment: There are no event handlers code. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Hi PEH. There are no formulas in the sheet as far as I can see. Most of the cells contain regular text, but some contain numbers stored as text (prefixed with '). I don't know if this can be an issue (that Excel somehow needs to convert these values each time)?

Comment: as far as I can say every read/write action to a cell causes heavy load and triggers the calculation event (at least for cells depending on that cell). But you can reduce that load by reading the data into an array and perform the calculations there and then write it back to the sheet. See [Working With Arrays](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/cells-ranges/vba-working-with-arrays.htm) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the inputs.

It turned out, that wrapping the code with the following statements solved the issue.
With these statements added, there is practically no jump in memory when running the method and the method takes few seconds to complete.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
...
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

I have been looking through the different sheets and modules for event-methods, but found none. But nonetheless, it must be SAP Analysis for Excel that somehow have eventbased code that takes up memory.